# Exclude records for column A when B is null

Tags: sql-server

Need help with a query that will let me exclude a record from column A if a record in column exist with a null.

Let's say i have two rows is column A named "test" they have column B values of 1 and null respectively. Here below is a query that I'm working on Object ID is column A and endversion is column B on my scenario.

```
select b.PortID, 
       max(endversion)as EndVersion, 
       d.ShortName as RuleName 
from xr.ObjectPropertyValue a 
       join moxyportfolio b on a.objectid=b.portkey 
       join xr.AssignAllObjectsRule c on a.Objectclassid=c.ObjectClassID -- can replace with xr.assignobjectrule if it's rule is not assigned to all portfolios.
       join xr.rulebase d on c.RuleID=d.RuleID 
where objectid in (select objectid from xr.objectpropertyvalue where endversion is not null) 
group by a.ObjectId, b.portid,d.ShortName
```

Comment: Is the endversion column coming from xr.ObjectPropertyValue table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `HAVING`:

```
select 
    b.PortID,
    max(endversion) as EndVersion,
    d.ShortName as RuleName 
from xr.ObjectPropertyValue a 
join moxyportfolio b 
    on a.objectid = b.portkey 
join xr.AssignAllObjectsRule c 
    on a.Objectclassid = c.ObjectClassID -- can replace with xr.assignobjectrule if it's rule is not assigned to all portfolios.
join xr.rulebase d 
    on c.RuleID = d.RuleID 
group by a.ObjectId, b.portid, d.ShortName
having sum(case when endversion is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Only select values for column A if column B is not null (and nothing otherwise):

```
 SELECT COLA
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE COLB IS NOT NULL
```

Only select a value for column A if column B is not null (and null otherwise):

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN COLB IS NOT NULL THEN COLA ELSE NULL END AS COLA
 FROM TABLE
```